# Открыть Navigation Drawer программным способом

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-navigation-drawer

Использую `Navigation Drawer` из стандартного примера от `Google`:

```
     if (mDrawerLayout.isShown()) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    } else {
                        //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                        //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout);
                        //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout.getForegroundGravity());
                    }
```

В этом коде часть, которая закрывает `Navigation Drawer`, работает без проблем, но ни один из способов, которые я вызываю для открытия, не работает: либо они просто игнорируются, либо я их использую неправильно (раскомментированные поочередно).

Так я инициализирую объекты для работы с `Navigation Drawer`:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                                   /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                          /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_ab_app,                   /* nav downloaded_list icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.vk_retry,                      /* "open downloaded_list" description */
                R.string.vk_new_post_settings           /* "close downloaded_list" description */
        ) {
            /**
             * Called when a downloaded_list has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                //getActionBar().setTitle("closed");
            }

            /**
             * Called when a downloaded_list has settled in a completely open state.
             */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                //getActionBar().setTitle("opened");
            }

        };
```

Comment: Поясните "не один из наведенных способов закрытия не работает". Кажется вы здесь очепятались.

Comment: Попробую в стороннем потоке это вызвать: new Thread() {
                            
                            public void run() {
                                SystemClock.sleep(100);
                                HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                                    } });
                            }
                        }.start();

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй метод `openDrawer()` без параметров. У меня работает.

Comment: без параметров выдает ошибку при компиляции ну и просто, если в редакторе открытым его оставить.Но спасибо за попытку+

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?